# How to name windsor registrations when using AllTypes

Tags: castle-windsor

I have an IWindsorInstaller class which I need to automagically name all the registrations

```cs
public class ImportInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(
            AllTypes
                .FromAssemblyNamed("ByBox.Import")
                .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Importer") && type.IsClass && type.IsPublic)
            );
    }
}
```

I'd like the name to be the classname.

So, equivalent of doing this for each class...

```cs
container.Register(
    Component.For<IMyImporter>()
        .ImplementedBy<MyImporter>()
        .Named("MyImporter")
);
```

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: AllTypes will filter out non-public and non-class types for you so you don't need to check for those conditions.

Comment: lol, i just said this in another comment "every day is a school day"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure...

```cs
    container.Register(
        AllTypes
            .FromAssemblyNamed("ByBox.Import")
            .Where(type => type.Name.EndsWith("Importer") && type.IsClass && type.IsPublic)
            .Configure(r => r.Named(r.Implementation.Name));
        );
```